# How to make a tap gesture intercept taps slightly outside the view as well

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have some views my user can tap. The functionality has been added to my views like this:

```swift
  let touchUpGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer { recognizer in
           print("something")
        }
        self.addGestureRecognizer(touchUpGesture)
```

My views look something like this:
[image]

And the tappable space is this:
[image]

However I want it to be this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the tap target that range of space without creating an invisible view and putting it below the actual view?

Comment: "creating an invisible view and putting it below the actual view" that's probably the easiest way to do this

Comment: Otherwise you could add the gesture recognizer to the enclosing view, get the location in that view coordinates (via `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s instance method `location(in:)`) and then test it against the view's subviews frames you're interested on with something like `let pointOfTap = tap.location(in: containerView); if let subViewTapped = containerView.subviews.first(where: { var enlarged = $0.frame; enlarged.inset(by: -offset); return enlarged.contains(pointOfTap) }) { // do your thing }`

Comment: You can override hitTest: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest. But I would use a clear view